# Javascript function not returning value

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I am calling a function with the following code:

```
var resultz = nsEditor.updateStringCall(debtID, column2Change, value2Change, 4, 10);
```

The function that is being called but doesn't return a value

```js
updateStringCall: function(pdebtID, pcolumn2Change, pvalue2Change, pmin, pmax){
    try {
        var resultz2 = 0;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Components/MintLibraries.cfc",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            data: {
                method: 'StringUpdate',
                val2Change: pvalue2Change.trim(),
                debtID: pdebtID,
                column2Change: pcolumn2Change,
                greaterThan: pmin,
                lesserThan: pmax,
                returnFormat: "json"
            },
            success: function(response) {
                resultz2 = 1;
                return resultz2;
            },  //end done
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                resultz2 = 0;
                return resultz2;
        }); //end ajax call
    } catch (e) {
        resultz2 = 0;
        return resultz2;
    }  //end trycatch
}, // end updateStringCall
```

This function uses the .ajax to call a coldfusion cfc method StringUpdate:

```
<cffunction name="StringUpdate" access="remote" output="false" returntype="any" >    
     <cfargument name="val2Change" type="string"  required="true" />
     <cfargument name="debtID"  type="string"  required="true" />
     <cfargument name="column2Change"  type="string"  required="true" />
     <cfargument name="greaterThan"  type="numeric"   required="false" />
     <cfargument name="lesserThan"  type="numeric"  required="false" />
     <cfset var debt2Pass = int(val(arguments.debtID)) />
     <cfset var updQuery = "" />
     <cfset var retValue = 0 />
     <cfset var iVal = 0 /><cfset var valError = '' />
    <cftry>
     
        <cfquery name="updQuery" datasource="#application.datasource#" result="qResults"    >
                Update dmf set #arguments.column2Change# =
                 <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.val2Change#"/>
                 where DebtID = 
                 <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_smallint" value="#arguments.debtID#"/>
        </cfquery> 
        <cfset retValue = 1 />    
     <cfcatch type="Any" >
                <cfset thrown = ThrowCFError(405,'debug',  'Error updating ' &  arguments.DebtID,arguments.val2Change & ', ' &  arguments.debtID & ',' & arguments.column2Change)  />
                  <cfset retValue = 0 />
         </cfcatch>
         </cftry>
    <cfreturn retValue />
</cffunction>
```

The query runs successfully but the js function doesn't return a value (it shows up as undefined).  Even if it gets an error, I would think I have accounted enough for that to at least get a return value.

Ideas?

Comment: Open up FireFox+Firebug, open the NET tab and look at your AJAX request and response. This may give you a clue.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The function is not returning a value because the `return`s in your method are embedded inside callback functions. They are only returning from those callbacks, not from your main function. Consider, for example, your "success" callback:

```
success: function(response) {
    resultz2 = 1;
    return resultz2;
}
```

This `return` is just returning from the `success` function... It doesn't bubble up to your `updateStringCall` function.

The reason it has to work this way is because ajax calls are asynchronous. Your method returns *immediately* while the request happens in the background. So in order to get the return value, you have to pass in a callback that has access to the value when it's ready, and then call the callback from within the ajax callbacks instead of returning a value.

So change your method definition to this:

```
// Note I added a "callback" parameter
function(pdebtID, pcolumn2Change, pvalue2Change, pmin, pmax, callback) { ... }
```

And then in your ajax callbacks, call it instead of returning a value:

```
success: function(response) {
    resultz2 = 1;
    callback(resultz2);
},
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    resultz2 = 0;
    callback(resultz2);
});
```

Finally, pass in a callback when you call this method:

```
nsEditor.updateStringCall(debtID, column2Change, value2Change, 4, 10, function(resultz) {
    // Do something with resultz
});
```

One final note, if you are going to have that blanket try/catch in there, you should change that to use the callback also:

```
catch (e) {
    resultz2 = 0;
    callback(resultz2);
}
```

But really, I'd recommend just taking that try/catch out altogether. I can't see how that can possibly be helpful here. It will only hide actual problems with code that *already* has a better structure for error handling. I suspect you just put in there to debug this return problem, but if it was there already, just take it out.

*This is the world of event-driven functional programming! It's a very common sort of structure in javascript.*

Comment: You are right, that is exactly why I put in the try/catch into the function and at one point during the writing of the scripts have had try/catch everywhere including the coldfusion cfc.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

Ajax calls are asynchronous. You'll have to work with your result from within the success callback of the $.ajax().

Answer (score 0):

Add `async: false` like this:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  async: false,
  url: "Components/MintLibraries.cfc",
  dataType: "json",
  cache: false,
})
```